# when i disconnect the azure user he remains in the saml2 session

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service, saml-2.0

I have an app integrated with saml2 on azure, on my system I always check to see if the user is logged in using:

```
$as = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('default-sp');
$as->requireAuth();
```

however when I log out the user from azure the requireAuth returns that the user is still logged in, only when I close the browser and enter it again it sends the user to log in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP `sessions` in `SimpleSAMLphp` will close any existing session when invoked for the first time, and its own session will prevail afterwards.

If you want to restore your own session after calling `SimpleSAMLphp`, you can cleaning up the session by using following steps:

```
$session = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$session->cleanup();
```

If you don't want to cleanup SimpleSAMLphp's session and try to use `$_SESSION` afterwards, you won't be using your own session and all your data is likely to get lost or inaccessible.

Note that if your application uses a [custom session handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php). You can lead to problems because `SimpleSAMLphp's` **stand-alone web UI** uses the default PHP session handlers. So, you need to unset the custom handler before making any calls to `SimpleSAMLphp`:

```
// use custom save handler
session_set_save_handler($handler);
session_start();

// close session and restore default handler
session_write_close();
session_set_save_handler(new SessionHandler(), true);

// use SimpleSAML\Session
$session = \SimpleSAML\Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$session->cleanup();
session_write_close();

// back to custom save handler
session_set_save_handler($handler);
session_start();
```

Refer [Doc](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp#section_6) & [SO thread for usage of session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853352/session-variables-not-working-after-require-simplesamlphp)

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo!!